# Getting 403 for a java website deployed on Azure

Tags: java, git, azure, web-applications

I am trying to deploy a simple java web application to MS Azure through git. When it deploys and i try to browse it , the website turns up with a 403 error saying "you don't have permission to view this page".

However if i convert my index.jsp page to index.html page (and remove the java specific code,off course). The website runs perfectly.

Does anybody have any insight to offer on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I know which URL you have used when tried to browse your site? If you did not put index.jsp in the URL, please try to use the full URL to see if it works, e.g. YourName.azurewebsites.net/index.jsp. Per my experience, index.html is in the default page list, but index.jsp is not. So if you can open the full URL with index.jsp, then you simply need to configure the default page using the Default Documents feature on the web app Settings page: YourWebApp CONFIGURE tab -> default documents section:

[image]

More info could be found at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/. If that still doesn't work, then please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/ to see whether it helps.